# Writing a Counter object to a CSV-file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, comparative-review, hash-map

In Python 3.4, a `Counter` object called `cnt` like this:

```
Counter({'0200': 3, '3000': 2, '3011': 2, '0210': 1, '4000': 1})
```

is to be written to a comma-separated file.

I first tried with CSV and `DictWriter` that I had not used before, but I kept getting misty errors and was pressed for time, so I decided to make this simple version (it works):

```
outfile = infile[:-4] + '_freq.csv'  
fp = open(outfile, encoding='utf-8-sig', mode='w')  
fp.write('KMC|freq\n')  
for tag, count in cnt.items():  
    fp.write('{}|{}\n'.format(tag, count))  

fp.close()
```

Then when I had some time I felt I should learn to use `DictWriter` and CSV, assuming it'd be 'better' or 'more pythonic'.

That turned into this (works too):

```
outfile2 = infile[:-4] + '_freq2.csv'  
with open(outfile2, encoding='utf-8-sig', mode='w', newline='') as f:
                # Note: empty newline to avoid blank lines in the output file 
    fieldnames = ['KMC', 'freq']  
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='|')  
    writer.writeheader()  
    for tag, count in cnt.items():  
        writer.writerow({'KMC': tag, 'freq': str(count)})
```

The trick with the empty newline to avoid blank lines is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29116560/1016065).

I like the first approach better. I think CSV and `DictWriter` are intended for much larger amounts of columns than the two small ones I got. But I'm no expert.

Any learned comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simplicity**

I think that, for an easy task like this, the **first version** is better as it is considerably simpler while accomplishing the same goal.

It can still be improved though:

**Cleaner deletion of file extension**

`infile[:-4]` is probably used to remove the extension from the file, but it is not obvious, I suggest `infile.replace(".txt","")`( 
where the extension may be different from `txt` but you get the idea).

**Context managing**

It is so easy to forget to close a file, it is better to use `with` that will close it automatically every time:

```
with open(outfile, encoding='utf-8-sig', mode='w') as fp:
fp.write('KMC|freq\n')  
for tag, count in cnt.items():  
    fp.write('{}|{}\n'.format(tag, count))
```

**Naming**

`cnt` is a mysterious name, I have no idea what kind of data it may contain, I suggest coming up with a better name.